# Get the latest record based on multiple columns - R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am trying to extract the latest record based on a combination of 3 columns. Below is my data along with the code to generate it:

[image]

```
test_df <- data.frame(KEY = c("AB101", "AB101","AB101" ,"PE105", "PE105", "PE105", "AB105", "AB105"), 
                     date = c("2014-08-26", "2014-08-26", "2014-05-26", "2015-12-23", "2015-12-23", 
                              "2015-10-23", "2016-09-23", "2016-09-23"),
                     decision = c("Accepted", "Rejected", "Rejected", "Accepted", "Rejected", "Rejected", 
                                  "Accepted", "Rejected"), 
                     date_time = c("2017-12-18 10:31:25", "2017-12-18 10:31:25", "2016-12-18 10:31:25", "2016-12-18 10:31:25",
                                   "2018-08-18 10:31:25", "2018-08-18 10:31:25", "2017-12-18 10:31:25", "2018-01-18 10:31:25"),
                     seq_num = c(104, 78, 84, 111, 89, 120, 102, 71))
```

I want to use the date, date_time and seq_num (in this order) to get the latest record:

Ideally the output should be like this:

[image]

NOTE: The seq_num should be 78 instead of 104.
So, the logic should say something like this:

Get the record with the maximum `date`. This will result in multiple rows, so then It should look at the `Date_time` column, which again could possibly result in multiple rows for each key. Then finally look at the `seq_num` and pull that row. 
So far I have the below code which works only on `date`. how do I add other conditions. Also it would be great if in the output the `date_time` and `date` columns could also show, just like the `seq_num` is showing.

Code:

```
df5 <- test_df %>% group_by(KEY) %>%
slice(which.max(date))
```

Comment: What you min by maximum date? Is it oldest date?

Comment: Why you have for `AB101` seq_num 104 instead of 78?

Comment: It means the latest date

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure is this what you mean but using `data.table` you can try

```
test_df <- data.frame(KEY = c("AB101", "AB101","AB101" ,"PE105", "PE105", "PE105", "AB105", "AB105"), 
                              date = as.Date(c("2014-08-26", "2014-08-26", "2014-05-26", "2015-12-23", "2015-12-23", 
                                       "2015-10-23", "2016-09-23", "2016-09-23"), "%Y-%m-%d"),
                              decision = c("Accepted", "Rejected", "Rejected", "Accepted", "Rejected", "Rejected", 
                                           "Accepted", "Rejected"), 
                              date_time = as.POSIXct(c("2017-12-18 10:31:25", "2017-12-18 10:31:25", "2016-12-18 10:31:25", "2016-12-18 10:31:25",
                                            "2018-08-18 10:31:25", "2018-08-18 10:31:25", "2017-12-18 10:31:25", "2018-01-18 10:31:25")),
                              seq_num = c(104, 78, 84, 111, 89, 120, 102, 71),
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(data.table)
setDT(test_df)[order(KEY, date, date_time),
               .(decision=decision[.N], seq_num=seq_num[.N]), KEY]
#returns
     KEY decision seq_num
1: AB101 Rejected      78
2: AB105 Rejected      71
3: PE105 Rejected      89
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three similar, but different solutions with `dplyr`:

```
test_df <- test_df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%  # Convert date to a date 
  group_by(KEY)
```

With the following solution several rows per group would remain, if there was a tie with `seq_num` at the end:

```
test_df %>% 
  top_n(1, date) %>%  # Takes all rows with the max. date
  top_n(1, decision) %>% # Takes all rows with the max decision 
  top_n(1, seq_num) # Takes all rows with max. seq_num
```

First arrange in descanding order and then take the first row per group:

```
test_df %>% 
  arrange(desc(date), desc(decision), -seq_num, .by_group = T) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

The same as above, but arranging everything ascending and then taking the last value per group:

```
test_df %>% 
  arrange(date, decision, seq_num, .by_group = T) %>% 
  slice(n())

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   KEY [3]
#   KEY   date       decision date_time           seq_num
#   <fct> <date>     <fct>    <fct>                 <dbl>
# 1 AB101 2014-08-26 Rejected 2017-12-18 10:31:25      78
# 2 AB105 2016-09-23 Rejected 2018-01-18 10:31:25      71
# 3 PE105 2015-12-23 Rejected 2018-08-18 10:31:25      89
```